# Excel 2010 - cell with LIST is not sorting

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to sort cells:

```
Sub RecordSort()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B3:B" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal

With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A3:P" & lastrow)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Range("A3").Select
End Sub
```

In column L I have a drop-down list with 5 codes. When I add a cell to the bottom of file, it has the drop-down in column L. Once I sort it (with the above macro) that row no longer has a drop-down list in column L. Is there a different way I should be sorting?

I'm sorting columns A thru P based on the contents of column B (which is a last name).

Comment: maybe you need to create or re-create the list after sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the data-validation applies to the cell itself, not to the value in the cell; so when you sort the values, the data-validation still applies to the original cell. The easiest fix would probably be to add the data-validation list to the entire column L by selecting the whole column and creating the validation rule -- is that an option?

Comment: File this under 'I did not know that'. I took your advice and added the `list` function to all the cells in column L, not just the one I was adding and it worked just fine. Thank you.